# How to install ANE Air Native Extension at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ane

Is any way to install and use ane extension from external module/swf.
As far i know, that extension files(ddl etc) is installed with native installer.
Is any way to install them in runtime, for example when external swf is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

On mobile: no - all code needs to be there at compile-time; you can't load any external code at runtime (through a SWF or ANE).

On desktop, it might be possible, as an ANE is essentially a SWC with some magic, but in that case, it would be easier to just use the SWC/SWF directly.